# R : calculation between columns

Tags: r

I have the following data.

```
> dat<-read.csv("datafile.csv",sep=",")
> dat
        V1      V2       V4       V5
1 908.1000 0.61884 2967.937 746.8904
2 914.2944 0.60927 2665.044 691.8030
3 920.4887 0.60038 2635.653 723.0173
>
```

I would like to calculate V6 as follows :-

V6=((V2-V5)/(V4-V5))*100

But I don't know how to do this with R.
Sorry, tried to use function such as lapply as found in some thread but to no success so far.
Any suggestion is very much welcomed.

thanks,
-we

Comment: `transform(dat, V6 = ((V2-V5)/(V4-V5))*100)` should work

Comment: Thanks David. This solved my headache.

Comment: See my `data.table` edit, could be useful package for you to learn how to use

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
(dat <- transform(dat, V6 = ((V2-V5)/(V4-V5))*100))
#         V1      V2       V4       V5        V6
# 1 908.1000 0.61884 2967.937 746.8904 -33.60000
# 2 914.2944 0.60927 2665.044 691.8030 -35.02835
# 3 920.4887 0.60038 2635.653 723.0173 -37.77075
```

---

Just for general knowledge, you can modify objects by reference (without creating unnecessary copies)  using the `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
(setDT(dat)[, V6 := ((V2-V5)/(V4-V5))*100])
#          V1      V2       V4       V5        V6
# 1: 908.1000 0.61884 2967.937 746.8904 -33.60000
# 2: 914.2944 0.60927 2665.044 691.8030 -35.02835
# 3: 920.4887 0.60038 2635.653 723.0173 -37.77075
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
> dat$V6 = with(dat, ((V2-V5)/(V4-V5))*100)
> dat
        V1      V2       V4       V5        V6
1 908.1000 0.61884 2967.937 746.8904 -33.60000
2 914.2944 0.60927 2665.044 691.8030 -35.02835
3 920.4887 0.60038 2635.653 723.0173 -37.77075
```